# thread Local Cached Connection

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I was using JMeter properties for storing the threadLocalCachedConnection object. I made sure to use unique property names as properties.

In thread group 1, I had a JSR223 PostProcessor to scrape session per thread(VU), and then store it in a property called sessionID.

[image]

And I added another JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the last sampler in the Thread Group1.

```
def connection = sampler.threadLocalCachedConnection
props.put("presenterConnection" + ctx.getThreadNum(), connection.get())
```

In Thread Group 2, I added a JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the first sampler.

```
def presenterConnection = props.get('presenterConnection' + ctx.getThreadNum())
sampler.threadLocalCachedConnection.set(presenterConnection)
```

[image]

```
String sendCommand = "SEND\n" +
         "content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8\n" +
         "destination:/v1/session/${__property(sessionId)}/command\n" +
         "id:perftest01-presenter-${__property(sessionId)}\n" +
           "\n" + 
           "{\"type\": \"go-to-slide\", \"data\": {\"index\": 0}}\n" +
           '\0'  // note: NULL char at end
           ;
vars.put("wsStompSendCommand", sendCommand);
```

I tested with 2 threads (VUs). Why both threads were using the last sessionId instead of using one sessionId per thread??

Comment: Please try with the option `Cache complied script if available` unchecked and run one more time.

Answer (score 2):

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; **properties are common to all threads**

so your line

```
props.put('sessionId', vars.get('sessionUUID'))
```

creates a global `sessionId` propety which is:

- common for all Threads no matter in which [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) they are
- exists until you shut down JMeter/[JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)

You need to play the same trick as with the `presenterConnection` to wit:

```
props.put('sessionId_'+ ctx.getThreadNum(), vars.get('sessionUUID'))
```

and then read it where required:

```
def sessionId =  props.get('sessionId_'+ ctx.getThreadNum())
```

More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)